# Convertir entero a valor monetario en datatables de jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Encontré en `DataTables` esta función:

```
render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' )
```

por el cual he intentado varias formas de poder inyectar ese pedacito de código, pero no he encontrado la forma.

**HTML:**

```
<table id="tabla_salario" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>salario</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>                                            
  </tbody>    
</table>
```

**JQUERY/AJAX:**

```
var tabla = $('#tabla_salario').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
             {
                 "targets": [ 0 ],
                 "visible": true
             }, 
         ],
     }); 



listar_datos();

function listar_datos()
{   
    $.ajax({
              url: 'listar_salario',
              type: 'POST'
          })
          .done(function(data)
          {
              var dato = $.parseJSON(data);

              for (var i = dato.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
              {
                  var rowNode = tabla
                  .row.add([ dato[i].salario, ])
                  .draw()
                  .node();
              }
          })
          .fail(function() {
              console.log("error");
          });  
      }
```

Este sería el ejemplo que necesito:

[image: números en formato $123,456,789]

¿Cómo podría incorporarlo en mi código?

Comment: que dato quieres convertir?

Comment: el salario que es el resultado que me trae el ajax de un controlador de php....dato[i].salario,<- este dato.

Comment: puedes poner un ejemplo del formato que quieres?

Comment: voy a editar la publicacion para que veas el ejemplo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trate de acoplarlo a tu codigo, pero decidi mejor dejarte un ejemplo.

nota: para que tu dinero tenga centavos, tu numero deberá ser float

**ejemplo:**

12.34

12 representa 12$ dolares

.34 representa 34$ centavos

```js
var numero = 1250.223;
var dinero = '$' + numero.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");

console.log(dinero);
```

Comment: listo hermano excelente, no necesariamente debe de ser un float con integer también me saca un decimal muchas gracias...100% funcional.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tabla = $('#tabla_salario').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
         {
             "targets": [ 0 ],
              render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 2, '$' )             
         }, 
     ],
 });
```